# Evince missing font in application menu

Tags: linux, linux-mint, fonts, evince

In Evince, the application menu seems to be missing a font. How can I fix this?

[image]

---

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3

Answer (score 1):

One cause of this seems to be when the UI font required is located on a different partition - which the security module `AppArmor` doesn't like. 
More information [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1396048).

Assuming the font is located within a directory somewhere like `/mnt/path/to/my/fonts`, you can try adding the line:

```
/mnt/path/to/my/fonts/**
```

(note double asterix) to end of the file:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/fonts
```

and then restart your system.